# Must i install django every time am starting a project in pycharm

Tags: python, django

i am just starting a new project on my pycharm i start a new project and run my server but am getting this error message couldn't import django, Must i install django for every project am creating?

Comment: No, I guess you forgot to switch to virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtual environment for every new project then you need to install django each time. Other wise you can use single virtual environment for all the project. It depends on you how you prefer. But I highly recommend you to use separate virtual environment for new project.